# How to share a project in Eclipse between 2 machines connected with a network cable

Tags: eclipse

I want to share my eclipse project with my room mate and I've connected two machines. I've no any idea with CVS .. can anyone help me? 
   Thanks.

Comment: Use version control. I like [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). Don't understand how? Ask a more-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your machines are connected, I suggest you set up a source control server on one of the two machines. There are some free products. I am using VisualSVN. I assume you are using Windows.

Comment: There is a binary package for Ubuntu. Check it at http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html